# Is it still safe to use sha1 as an hmac hash function in 2018

Tags: hmac, sha-1

I'm curious if it's safe to use sha1 for an HMAC in 2018 in a platform product.

A popular vendor (Twilio) uses an HMAC with sha1 with a shared secret to validate that messages they send are indeed sent by them (see the [Twilio docs on validating messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests))..

In a recent audit, the use of sha1 was flagged as a potential problem.

As part of the explanation and justification for why it is OK to use hmac-with-sha1, Twilio pointed to [this article](http://dev.ionous.net/2009/03/hmac-vs-raw-sha-1.html) about hmac with sha1, though I note that article is from 2009.

So, what say you crypto.stackexchange? Is it still safe in 2018 for an organization like Twilio to use sha1 in an HMAC?

Comment: Yes, still secure, but they should migrate away none-the-less. If they say that this is impossible you can ask them to explain why it is impossible for them to upgrade the protocol and *consequently* what their upgrade strategy is. That question will probably make them sweat a bit :)